# Как в plpgsql выбрать строки удовлетворяющие условию вхождения значения колонки в массив?

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql, plpgsql

Как записать условие вхождения значения колонки в массиве? Там где закомментированная строка, а именно

> id in (ids)

.

```
do $$
declare
    ids int[];
    res text[];
begin
    create temp table test (
        id bigserial,
        name text,

        constraint test_pk primary key(id)
    );

    insert into test(name) values
        ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8');

    ids := '{1, 3, 5, 7}'::int[];

    -- select array_agg(name) from test where id in (ids) into res; -- ERROR
    raise notice '%', res;
end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как любопытным ненавязчиво поясняет `explain`, условие `in (1,2,3)` на самом деле лишь преобразуется в искомую вами форму условия:

```
explain select * from test where id in (1,2,44);
                              QUERY PLAN                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=8.48..15.59 rows=3 width=40)
   Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,44}'::bigint[]))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_pk  (cost=0.00..8.48 rows=3 width=0)
         Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,44}'::bigint[]))
```

Вам же нужен как раз не in, а непосредственно само условие над массивом `id = ANY (ids)`